# I would like to put a word counter in this code but can't

Tags: java

I need to be able to count the number of words I put into the string that I enter. I have tried many different things and none of them have worked for me

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter some text: ");
    String str = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    String vowels = "aeiou";
    System.out.println(str);

    int vcount = 0;
    int ccount = 0;

for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {

  if (Character.isLetter(c)) {

      if (vowels.indexOf(c) >= 0) 
      {
        vcount++;
      }
      else
      {
        ccount++;
        }
    }   
}

    System.out.print("your input has " + vcount + " vowels" + "\n");
    System.out.print("your input has " + ccount + " consonants" + "\n");
    //System.out.print("your input has " + words + " words");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the string on whitespace and the length of the resulting array is your word count:

```
int wordcount = str.split( "\\s+" ).length;
```

The "\\s+" is a regex that matches one or more whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

The regex approach is for sure reasonable.
But if you are just starting to learn programming, maybe the folowing approach might be more suited.

Lets' start by defining what a "word" is. One option: "a sequence of one or more consecutive letters".

So when iterating through the characters, we can have the following situations:

- We are already in a word and another letter is found -> still in a word
- We are already in a word and anything other than a letter is found -> not in a word any more
- We are not in a word and a letter is found -> we found a new word
- We are not in a word and anything other than a letter is found -> still not in a word

So we have to keep track of "we are in a word" by a boolean variable.

Translated to code:

```
int vcount = 0;
int ccount = 0;
int wcount = 0;
boolean inword = false;

for (char c : str.toCharArray()) 
{
    if (Character.isLetter(c)) 
    {
        if (vowels.indexOf(c) >= 0) 
        {
            vcount++;
        }
        else
        {
            ccount++;
        }
        if (!inword)
        {
            inword = true;
            wcount++;
        }
    }   
    else
    {
        inword = false;
    }
}
```